# .Net Page Responds with Portion of the Response Body Missing

Tags: c#, .net, iis, iis-7

I'm experiencing an intermittent error.

We have a page which, when viewing source in a client browser returns ~5800 lines of javascript and html markup.

However, intermittently, a random portion of the response body is missing. For instance we might get 5600-5700 lines instead of the 5800 that we are expecting.

This causes a variety of errors, depending on which lines get cut off. The number of missing lines and the position of the lines is random.

So far I am still in the research phase of just trying to figure out what is happening in the first place. We haven't tried anything yet to fix the problem.

I have placed breakpoints at OnPreRender, Render, and OnUnload. The debugger hit all three breakpoints without any exceptions being thrown. The debugger was set to pause execution upon any exception, handled or unhandled.

Any ideas of what could cause this behavior?

**An example of one of the cut off responses:**

```
this.message = "Please enter yo
="checked" /><label for="rememberMe">Keep me signed in</label>
```

So as you can see there is a random chunk of the response missing between where we were doing some javascript and where we had some markup.

**Update/Fix**
For some strange reason turning on compression in IIS fixes the problem. But that still doesn't make much sense and I'm still very curious what caused the problem and why compression should fix it.

Comment: Might I suggest using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to view the interaction between your client browser and server? You might find some insight.

Comment: Yep, fiddler was our how we first discovered something strange happening. It would show response headers, including a correct content-length header, but wouldn't show the response body and even though the response header said 200/OK, fiddler showed no HTTP result and that it was still downloading the response, likely because it hadn't recieved enough content to match the content length header.

Comment: Michael, post your current solution as an answer. Even though it may not be the ultimate correct or best one, it's still one potential resolution for someone if they encounter the same thing.

Comment: Have you tested this with different browsers?

Comment: Most recent versions of IE ad Firefox, didn't test chrome or safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some strange reason turning on compression in IIS fixes the problem. But that still doesn't make much sense and I'm still very curious what caused the problem and why compression should fix it.